# Refresh div only with server time rather than JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I am able to somehow have my div refresh in server seconds rather a jquery timer?

Or possibly to not have the timer start until all images have loaded?

This method works however it goes out of sync quite often, possibly because of some images still trying to load.

This code was sourced online

Markup:

```
refreshing in <div id="countDown"></div>
```

Refresh div after 10 seconds:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(' #avatars').load(' #avatars');
refresh();
}); 

function refresh()
{
setTimeout( function() {
    $(' #avatars').load(' #avatars');
    refresh();
}, 10000);
}
```

Jquery 15sec timer, resets back to 15 after 0

```
window.onload = function() {
startCountDown(10, 1000, myFunction);
}
function startCountDown(i, p, f) {
var pause = p;
var fn = f;
var countDownObj = document.getElementById("countDown");

countDownObj.count = function(i) {
//  write out count
countDownObj.innerHTML = i;
if (i == 0) {
//  execute function
    fn();
    startCountDown(10, 1000, myFunction);
    //  stop
    return;
}
setTimeout(function() {
        //  repeat
        countDownObj.count(i - 1);
}, pause);
}
//  set it going
countDownObj.count(i); 
}

function myFunction(){};
```

Comment: You want when the load is complete then call the refresh() function ; is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delay the timer until your image loads couldn't you use the callback function on $('#avatars').load('#avatars'); to start the timer?

```
function refresh(){
  $('#avatars').load('#avatars', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      refresh();
    }, 10000);
    startCountDown(10, 1000, myFunction);
  });
}
```

I believe that this wouldn't start the count down until the images finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

Call refresh function when load status is success.See for more in here http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#avatars").load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
    // debugger;
     if (statusTxt == "success") 
        {   
         refresh();     
        }
    if (statusTxt == "error") 
        {
         console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        }
   });
```